# Linux 'w' command, get IDLE time in seconds

Tags: linux, bash

I need to get idle time of all users in seconds (not minutes or days), how do i go about doing it ? 
This command lists the idle times of all connected users :

```
w | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print $1,$5 }}'
```

OUTPUT:

```
USER IDLE
root 4:29m
root 105days
root 2days
root 10:49m
root 7.00s
root 4:27m
```

How do i make it convert days and minutes into seconds ?

Comment: Is this question being downvoted because it requires a lot of work to solve ? Yes i know a script is required to look for m/s/days/empty and convert accordingly, i need help making one...

Comment: You are approaching this from the wrong angle - converting the idle time from the `w` output is possible but too much work. You have to look for a way to get the raw data that `w` uses to print the idle time. One way would be to look at the ctime of the tty/pty associated with the `w` output, e.g. `/dev/tty0` or `/dev/pts/0` - this time changes whenever the user is active. See `man stat` and `man date`.

Comment: Related: [How does the \`w\` command know the idle time and the running command?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/231383)

Answer (score 9):

The idle time is nothing more complicated than the last access time of the TTY device that the user is logged in from. So a simple way of doing this would be to grab all the names of the TTYs people are logged in on and `stat` them:

```
who -s | awk '{ print $2 }' | (cd /dev && xargs stat -c '%n %U %X')
```

On some systems, that will emit errors for login sessions such as X11 sessions which aren't on real ttys.

If you want the age instead of the absolute time, post-process it to subtract it from the current time:

```
who -s | awk '{ print $2 }' | (cd /dev && xargs stat -c '%n %U %X') |
    awk '{ print $1"\t"$2"\t"'"$(date +%s)"'-$3 }'
```

Or use `perl`'s `-A` operator:

```
who -s | perl -lane 'print "$F[1]\t$F[0]\t" . 86400 * -A "/dev/$F[1]"'
```

Comment: Note that the device's owner is not necessarily the same as the person who logged in on that terminal

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas when would it be different?

Comment: Here on a Linux Mint system, I see it for /dev/tty7 with a X11 login session, where the tty device is still owned by root, while the utmp entry has my user name

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I see. I guess the modification time on `/dev/tty7` probably also has nothing to do with your X11 session. Here (Debian jessie) my X11 login session shows tty `:0` which is not a real tty and you can't get an idle time out of it anyway (`w` shows `?xdm?` in the IDLE column).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Re: modification time vs. last access time: TIL!

Comment: Me too actually. I realised it when trying to find out when the modification and access times were being updated. Did you know that neither were updated upon user input? Even with local echo on. Only reads and writes to the device update them.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most elegant code, and it can be shortened, but that is for your homework :-)

```bash
w |awk '{
if (NR!=1){ 
if($5 ~ /days/){ 
    split($5,d,"days");
    print $1,d[1]*86400" sec"
}
else if( $5 ~ /:|s/){
    if ($5 ~/s/) { sub(/s/,"",$5); split($5,s,"."); print $1,s[1]" sec" }
    else if ( $5 ~/m/) { split($5,m,":"); print $1,(m[1]*60+m[2])*60" sec" }
    else { split($5,m,":"); print $1,m[1]*60+m[2]" sec" }
}
else { print $1,$5}
}}'
```

Comment: Nope, it doesnt work. If you could modify it so it at least converts days to sec. i could do the rest :)

Comment: em, well, the first case converts days to the seconds. what exactly does not work? just checked even with your example; it returns correct values; root 16140 sec
root 544320000 sec
root 10368000 sec
root 38940 sec
root 0 sec
root 16020 sec

Comment: My bash version 4.1.2(1)-release wont run it.   awk: cmd. line:5: case /days/: 
awk: cmd. line:5:            ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:8: case /:|s/:
awk: cmd. line:8:       ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:14: default:
awk: cmd. line:14:        ^ syntax error

Comment: it's not about bash version, it's about your {g}awk version, which is not compiled with the switch support. so i've changed it to if/else. please check it now.

Comment: We are almost there!! it converts everything correctly except XX:XXm format.  8:03m for example ends up as 0 secs

Comment: yeah, my bad missed to change param from $2 to $5 :)

Comment: Well this sure does deserve a $5! :) If you provide your bitcoin address below i'll send it over right now. Thanks!!

Comment: Ahh, the calculations in the latest version are off. Idle times : 1. 26days 2. 1:10m 3. 6.00s end up as 1. 134784000 sec 2. 4080 sec 3. 6 secs. Everything other than secs. is off :(

Comment: *5184000 this part of the code is off, it shoudl be 86400

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash solution:

```bash
WishSeconds () {

    # PARM 1: 'w -ish' command idle time 44.00s, 5:10, 1:28m, 3days, etc.
    #      2: Variable name (no $ is used) to receive idle time in seconds

    # NOTE: Idle time resets to zero when user types something in terminal.
    #       A looping job calling a command doesn't reset idle time.

    local Wish Unit1 Unit2
    Wish="$1"
    declare -n Seconds=$2

    # Leading 0 is considered octal value in bash. Change ':09' to ':9'
    Wish="${Wish/:0/:}"

    if [[ "$Wish" == *"days"* ]] ; then
        Unit1="${Wish%%days*}"
        Seconds=$(( Unit1 * 86400 ))
    elif [[ "$Wish" == *"m"* ]] ; then
        Unit1="${Wish%%m*}"
        Unit2="${Unit1##*:}"
        Unit1="${Unit1%%:*}"
        Seconds=$(( (Unit1 * 3600) + (Unit2 * 60) ))
    elif [[ "$Wish" == *"s"* ]] ; then
        Seconds="${Wish%%.*}"
    else
        Unit1="${Wish%%:*}"
        Unit2="${Wish##*:}"
        Seconds=$(( (Unit1 * 60) + Unit2 ))
    fi

} # WishSeconds

WishSeconds "20days" Days ; echo Passing 20days: $Days
WishSeconds "1:10m"  Hours ; echo Passing 1:10m: $Hours
WishSeconds "1:30"   Mins ; echo Passing 1:30: $Mins
WishSeconds "44.20s" Secs ; echo Passing 44.20s: $Secs
```

### Results

```bash
Passing 20days: 1728000
Passing 1:10m: 4200
Passing 1:30: 90
Passing 44.20s: 44
```